# Can an auto insurance firm ( US) raise rates based on old age?

Tags: united-states, insurance

My auto insurance went up 30% this year. I am 82 and my wife is 77.

As far as I can recall, we have had just 1 or 2 claims in the last 50 years. 10 years ago, my wife backed into a parked car causing no damage to her car but dented a door and fender on the other car. About 15 years ago I had a tailgate repaired; I paid, but I don't remember if it was the deductible or the whole cost. Our cars are ordinary, a 2004 and a 2011.

I don't see anything in our history to warrant a 30% increase. So I am thinking it is our ages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule on what an auto insurance company can base rates on vary by state within the US. In at least some states age is a permitted category. In many states drivers younger than 25 pay a higher rate.

But even if someone confirmed that rates may be legally based on age in the OP's state, that wouldn't prove that OP's insurance company actually used age to set rates.

OP could ask the agent who manages the policy, or the company that issues it, if age is a factor and why rates when up.

Note that rates are based in part on accident and claim rates in the area where a car is garaged and used -- if for some reason accident rates in OP's town or region went up -- say a new road or mall led to many more collisions or thefts -- that could cause a raise for everyone in the area, with no change in claim history for OP personally.